# Creating a presentation with R + markdown + knitr + equations + pandoc + reveal.js

Tags: r, pandoc, mathjax

I am stuck. I am trying to find the right combination of tools to achieve a presentation which would include mathematical equations, dynamically generated plots and which would be pleasing to the eye. I am stuck with equations. Here is what I have so far:

I create an .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Test RMD"
author: Foofary Finer
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

# First slide

$$2^{10} - 1$$

# Second slide

```{r plot1}
plot(1:10,1:10)
```
````

(How can I produce directly the html using rmarkdown::render? But that's another question)

Running knitr("test.Rmd") creates the following markdown code:

````
---
title: "Test RMD"
author: Foofary Finer
date: "2015-06-22"
---

# First slide

$$2^{10} - 1$$

# Second slide


```r
plot(1:10,1:10)
```

![plot of chunk plot1](figure/plot1-1.png)
````

So far, so good. Now I run pandoc:

```
pandoc   -s  -S -i -t revealjs  test.md -o test.html --mathjax
```

The maths does not get rendered. Inspection of the HTML code reveals the following line:

```
<script src="//cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Apparently, the "https:" is missing; if I correct it manually, the math is displayed correctly. So what am I doing wrong? I tried the following, but to no avail:

```
pandoc -s  -S -i -t revealjs  test.md -o test.html --mathjax -V mathjax-url='https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML'
```

Comment: `src="//cdn.mathjax.org` means to use the same url scheme as is currently used (http or https). So if you serve the file from a webserver, it will actually work. But if you open it with `file://`, it won't work.

Comment: OK, I see. So what should I do to have a local file that I can use for presentations? Put it in the Apache installation on my laptop? (it appears that this is the case, actually...)

Comment: According to [the pandoc docs](http://pandoc.org/README.html#math-rendering-in-html) the syntax is ` --mathjax=URL`. Maybe try that?

Comment: Indeed. However, is there a way to make 'file:///...' work?

Comment: Ops. My bad. I tried it again with using just "MathJax/..." (without "file:///") -- and it works.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.